# Why did Juergen Hoeller create HierarchicalBeanFactory?

Tags: spring

What does this class do?

```
public interface HierarchicalBeanFactory extends BeanFactory {

    /**
     * Return the parent bean factory, or {@code null} if there is none.
     */
    @Nullable
    BeanFactory getParentBeanFactory();

    /**
     * Return whether the local bean factory contains a bean of the given name,
     * ignoring beans defined in ancestor contexts.
     * <p>This is an alternative to {@code containsBean}, ignoring a bean
     * of the given name from an ancestor bean factory.
     * @param name the name of the bean to query
     * @return whether a bean with the given name is defined in the local factory
     * @see BeanFactory#containsBean
     */
    boolean containsLocalBean(String name);

}
```

Comment: It a specialized `BeanFactory` that can have a parent. With the fact that you have a parent comes also the fact that the bean can be local (i.e. in this context) or not but available in the parent. Your question is quite broad and the javadoc states the specifics for this interface.

Answer (score 1):

A HierarchicalBeanFactory makes sense for example in a web application to enforce a separation between the business layers (service and persistance) and the presentation layers (controllers and forms).

The rule is that the beans from the presentation layer can use beans of the business layers but the business layer should not even be aware of the web related layers. So we have:

- business layers: parent bean factory
- web related layers: child bean factory

Of course in real application we do not use raw bean factories, but plain `ApplicationContext` objects...